# Pop ups are not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app that needs to access both the user's location and calendar, a pop up should appear but for some reason it is not showing and I keep getting denied, here is the code for the calendar access :

```
- (void)askAuthorization
{

    EKAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    BOOL needsToRequestAccessToEventStore = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined);

    if (needsToRequestAccessToEventStore) {
        [self.store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                // Access granted
                NSLog(@"User granted access");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.delegate userDidAuthorizeCalendarReadingsWithError:error];
                });

            } else {
                // Denied
                NSLog(@"User did not grant access. To grant access, go to Settings > Privacy > Calendars > VirtualAssitant");
                [self.delegate userDidNotAuthorizeCalendarReadingsWithError:error];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.delegate userDidAuthorizeCalendarReadingsWithError:error];
                });

            }
        }];
    }
```

}

I am not getting a pop up and `AuthorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent` value is "denied"!

As for the location I went to settings-> privacy-> location,  found it set to never for my application and I had to manually change it to always. 
does anyone know why or has been through the same problem and can help me.

I tried cleaning the build folder and reseting Location and Privacy settings but when I rebuild my application the same thing happen I don't get a pop up asking for permission and the values are set to denied!

Answer (score 0):

The permission pop up for any system access like camera, photo album, location, contacts, etc... will only appear once (for each access type).

Once it has been presented and then accepted or denied then it will never appear again.

Because it has come back with the permission "denied" this means it has already appeared and you tapped on "do not allow".

The only way to change the permission in the app after that is to go into the app settings and change it manually.

You can force the permission pop-up to appear again by deleting the app from your device and then installing it again.

Comment: I also tried to delete the app from the device and install it again and I got the same issue I even tried it on different devices but no pop up is showing and the value is always denied.